# Is "value not in list" same as "not value in list"?

Tags: python

The two forms `value not in list` and `not value in list` return the same result.

Are they equivalent or is one better than the other?

```
>>> l=[1,2,3]
>>> 1 not in l
False
>>> not 1 in l
False
>>> 5 not in l
True
>>> not 5 in l
True
```

Comment: I'd say it's value not in list vs not value in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in:

> x in s evaluates to true if x is a member of the collection s, and false otherwise. x not in s returns the negation of x in s

So, `x not in s` is indeed the same as `not x in s`. Whether one is better than the other is a matter of style; personally, I'd say that `x not in s` reads better.

Answer (score 1):

I would say `value not in list` is better simply because of readability. `not value in list` is confusing. Code should be as readable as possible.